# How Do I repeat a calculation until I cross a threshold in Google Sheets

Tags: spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a Google Sheet I'm using to evaluate financial goals. In this sheet, I have 8 cells. The first two cells are used to enter parameters that are used by the formulas in the other cells.

The first cell is a parameter that generates the result in cell 7. The second cell is a threshold I want to reach. Basically, I want to take the value in cell 1 and increase it by 1 until the result seen in cell 7 crosses the value in cell 2. An example looks like this:

```
  A                        B
1 Current Total            $10000
2 Target Amount            $1000
3 Current Amount           =DIVIDE(B1, 100)
4 Result A                 =PRODUCT(B3, 0.35)
5 Result B                 =PRODUCT(B3, 0.50)
6 Result C                 =PRODUCT(B3, 0.15)
7 TOTAL                    =SUM(B4:B6)
8 Total Needed             ?
```

Using the example above, I want to create a formula that increases the value B1 by 1 until the value in B7 crosses the value in B2. I want to put the amount used to cross the threshold in cell B8.

I would prefer to do this repeat operation "behind the scenes" so only the result appears in cell B8. I don't want to show all of the "work". Is there a way to do this in a Google Sheet? If so, how?

Comment: Provide some hand-made example with the source data and the result view which you want to achieve.

Comment: @Akina - I added a simplifed version of what I'm trying to do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `B8=(B2-B7)*100`... and if replace `B1` value to `OLD(B1)+B8` then `B7 =B2`.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but to whom it may concern. `Total Needed` will hold value

```
=(B1 * (B2/B3)) - B1
```

---

> I would prefer to do this repeat **operation "behind the scenes" so only**
> **the result appears in cell B8**. I don't want to show all of the "work".
> Is there a way to do this in a Google Sheet? If so, how?

This is achievable with Menu -> Extensions -> Google Apps Script - > [Add Custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions). But anyway you and anybody will see nothing from the calculation because its enough fast.

*Variant 1*
**My suggestion is to solve this by calculation formula which
calculates the amount of times, needed to add 1**

B3 is 1% of Current Total. Divide `Target Amount by Current Amount` to take 1% of Target Amount. Its simple math.

```
B8 = B2/B3
```

Multiply the result by Current Total. This will give how many times 1% of Target Amount has in Current Total

```
B8 = (B2/B3) * B1
```

Next, substract the Current Total from the result. This is needed because we need to know - how many times we have to add 1, after the added value of Current Total,

> until the result in cell 7 crosses the value in cell 2

```
B8 = ((B2/B3) * B1) - B1

   A                  B
1 Current Total      10000
2 Target Amount       1000
3 Current Amount     = B1 / 100
4 Result A           = B3 * 0.35
5 Result B           = B3 * 0.50
6 Result C           = B3 * 0.15
7 TOTAL              = SUM(B4:B6)
8 Total Needed       = ((B2/B3) * B1) - B1
```

---

*If you have similar case which is difficult to solve - try to give good names of the properties it has. Let the names talk about the values they hold. This will help while thinking over it.*

Exclude all values that have already been calculated.

`Current Amount` is 100% of Current Total, B3 = B1/100. So think about, this cell will always hold that value whenever you calculating in that case - it will always be `=B1/100`.

`Results A, B and C` are same as Current Amount. They are parts from Current Total, too. `Result A` is 35% from Current Total... and so on the others. Each of them will always have the same value.

`TOTAL` will always be equal to Current Amount, because it summaries the parts of it. Its a hardcoded value, too.

Now, separate known properties from the others. They all represent same one value - the parts of the Current Total - and you don't have to think about their calculation, because they have hardcoded values.

```
   A                        B
1 Current Total                              
2 Target Amount            __________________
3 Current Amount           = B1 / 100
4 Result A                 = B3 * 0.35
5 Result B                 = B3 * 0.50
6 Result C                 = B3 * 0.15
7 TOTAL                    = SUM(B4:B6)
8 Total Needed             __________________
```

Now, values left to work are - Current Total and Target Amount.

---

> Using the example above, I want to create a formula that **increases the
> value B1 by 1 until the value in B7 crosses the value in B2**. I want to
> put the amount used to cross the threshold in cell B8.

*Variant 2*
**Increase the value of B1 by 1, only by yourself, manually.**

Test with D1 in column C, when C7=C2 the result will populate C8, else you have to increase, or decrease D1:

```
   A                  B                 C                      D 
1 Current Total      10000             = B1+D1            --> 90000 <--
2 Target Amount      ____________      1000
3 Current Amount     = B1 / 100        = C1/100
4 Result A           = B3 * 0.35       = C3*0.35
5 Result B           = B3 * 0.50       = C3*0.5
6 Result C           = B3 * 0.15       = C3*0.15
7 TOTAL              = SUM(B4:B6)      = SUM(C4:C6)
8 Total Needed       ____________      = IF(C7=C2; D1; "Change D1")
```